# Semidefinite Program formulation

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization

I have the following problem and would like to formulate that as an SDP. I am not sure how to approach this :

A set $S$ is given such that :
$$ S = \{P \in R^{n \times m} : ||p_i - c_i|| \leq d_i \}$$ 
Here $c_i \in R^n$ is the i-th column of $C$ and $d_i \in R^+ $. Another full-column rank matrix $M$ is $ n \times m $

$P^TB + B^TP $ is PSD $ \forall \ \ P \in S$

Then I have to convert the following optimization problem into an SDP 
$$\min_P tr(P(I_m + P^TB + B^T)^{-1}P^T)$$  such that $$P \in S $$

How would I atleast approach this to convert into the following form :

$$ \min C \cdot X $$
such that $$ A_i \cdot X = b_i$$
$$ x \geq 0$$
Here, $ X \in R^{n \times n}$ , $A_i \in R^{n \times n}$ , $ b_i \in R $ and $C \in R^{n \times n} $